# How do you handle a event for an ASP.NET server control inside another server control?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page on which there is a Loginview control. I put a Detailsview inside this Loginview control. Now I want to write a handler for a Detailsview event but this Detailsview object is not on the dropdown list from the code file(aspx.vb file)(because this object is in the Loginview container). How do I write the event handler then? Is it a common scenario to write a handler for an object inside a container during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the server control either in design view or source view in Visual Studio-click the Event button in Property Window-select "OnEvent"-type the name of the event handle you want to name-finish. In the code page the event handle will be auto-generated. Complete it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

ok so not sure what you're saying, but yes, you can handle any event anywhere as long as it is not private.

so here is how you'd implement an event inside of your container control (textbox example)

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(tb_Loaded);

void tb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {..}
```